# Problems with Umlaut in bookmark when using acrobat reader

Tags: luatex, bookmarks

I am using the class `altacv` which can be found [here](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV). I am also using the command `\includepdf` to include a pdf in my document and to the table of contents. Now my problem is that if I use an umlaut, like ä, in the title in \includepdf and open the generated pdf with the acrobat reader the title of the included pdf shows weird symbols instead of the ä in the bookmark. I compile with LuaLatex.

I already looked the problem up and found out that the option pdfencoding=auto in the hyperref package could be the solution. But I do not know how to integrate this option to my tex file. I only get the error message of clashed
options...

```
% This is an sample CV template created using altacv.cls
% (v1.3, 10 May 2020) written by LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com). Now compiles with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.
%
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% If you are using \orcid or academicons
%% icons, make sure you have the academicons
%% option here, and compile with XeLaTeX
%% or LuaLaTeX.
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,academicons]{altacv}

%% Use the "normalphoto" option if you want a normal photo instead of cropped to a circle
% \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,normalphoto]{altacv}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e,withhyper]{altacv}
%% AltaCV uses the fontawesome5 and academicons fonts
%% and packages.
%% See http://texdoc.net/pkg/fontawesome5 and http://texdoc.net/pkg/academicons for full list of symbols. You MUST compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX if you want to use academicons.

% Change the page layout if you need to
\geometry{left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,columnsep=1.2cm}

% The paracol package lets you typeset columns of text in parallel
\usepackage{paracol}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Roboto Slab}
  \setsansfont{Lato}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[rm]{roboto}
  \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
  % \usepackage{sourcesanspro}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\definecolor{DarkPastelRed}{HTML}{450808}
\definecolor{PastelRed}{HTML}{8F0D0D}
\definecolor{GoldenEarth}{HTML}{E7D192}
\colorlet{name}{black}
\colorlet{tagline}{PastelRed}
\colorlet{heading}{DarkPastelRed}
\colorlet{headingrule}{GoldenEarth}
\colorlet{subheading}{PastelRed}
\colorlet{accent}{PastelRed}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change some fonts, if necessary
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\Huge\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\personalinfofont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cvsectionfont}{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsubsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}


% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\usepackage{pdfpages} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={
     1,section,1,Chapter Ä,p1}]{example.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Please replace example.pdf by an arbitrary pdf. If I open this tex file with acrobat reader there are weird symbols instead of the Ä in the bookmark.

Comment: Please show us the code you're using (aka an MWE) … I suspect that the external PDF is encoded as ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin-1), while you are using UTF-8 (hopefully). But, impossible to say without a closer look.

Comment: no luatex need `pdfencoding=unicode`, (which is the default in a current hyperref), auto encoding is wrong.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to solve the problem with the umlaut in the bookmark?

Comment: with a current texlive/hyperref and a current version of your class the Umlaut is fine.

Comment: Updated all the packages and now it works! Thank you for the help!